# Validation New Form MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, spring-mvc

I need your help.I am doing a project in MVC and have downloaded a new Register form from Internet. All works fine, but I want to create in this form the error message when the user insert th e data(e.g. for wrong email,password etc.).I created new layout for my form:

```
    @model WebApp.Models.User

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Register</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/UsefullBox/fonts/material-icon/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/UsefullBox/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="signup-content">
            <div class="signup-form">
                <h2 class="form-title">Register Form</h2>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "register-form", @id = "register-form" }))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"><i class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User_login, new { @placeholder = "Your Name" })<br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User_login, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email"><i class="zmdi zmdi-email"></i></label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User_Email, new { @placeholder = "Your Email" })<br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User_Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock"></i></label>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.User_password, new { @placeholder = "Password" })<br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User_password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="re-pass"><i class="zmdi zmdi-lock-outline"></i></label>
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.User_password_1, new { @placeholder = "Repeat your password" })<br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User_password_1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group form-button">
                        <input type="submit" name="signup" id="signup" class="form-submit" value="Register" />
                    </div>  }               
            </div>
            <div class="signup-image">
                <figure><img src="~/UsefullBox/images/signup-image.jpg" alt="sing up image"></figure>
                <a href="#" class="signup-image-link">I am already member</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And this is my class:
     public partial class User
        {
            public int User_Id { get; set; }

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the login")]
        public string User_login { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string User_password { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Reenter the password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("User_password")]
        public string User_password_1 { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter email")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage ="Invalid Email Address")]
        public string User_Email { get; set; }       
    }
```

what i have to insert more in my code that when the client insert e.g. a wrong email, the form show the Error Message.Thank you!!! Exemple: https://learn-the-web.algonquindesign.ca/courses/web-dev-4/designing-form-errors/

Comment: Have you check in Action `ModelState.Isvalid`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string User_Email { get; set; }
```

Or you can use Regex

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
```